# Chaining .live() events to functions

Tags: jquery, function, click, live, chain

I cannot get focused to update with the current value. Is there a bug in this code or is there a cleaner approach I am missing? Can I pass 'this'  or the 'event'?

I am getting this error:

```
'focused is not defined'
```

I have this block of code:

```
$("input, select, textarea, button, .link, div, .button").live({
  click:clearDefault,
  focusin:function() {focused = ($(this).attr('title'))},
  focusout:function() {focused = false},
  mouseover:onHelp,
  mouseout:helpFallback
});
```

Which maps to these functions:

```
function onHelp() {
if (!helpDiv) {
    helpDiv = $('#helpText');
}
var $this = $(this);
var text = $this.attr('title');
if ($this.attr('titlehtml')) {
    var text = $this.attr('titlehtml');
}
if ($this.hasClass('screenshot')) {
    text += "<img src='images/icon_table_" + $this.attr('id') + ".png' >";
}
if ($this.attr('errorhtml')) {
    text += "<div id='userError'>"+$this.attr('errorhtml')+"</div>";
}
helpDiv.show().html(text);
}

function helpFallback() {
    if (focused) {
        helpDiv.show().html(focused);
    } else {
        helpDiv.hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you actually _define_ `focused`? I don't see `var focused = false;` anywhere.

Comment: look at second block of code.. ooo. you mean `var focused = '';`? Yep thats it....

Comment: Hmmm... I don't see `var focused = '';` anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define focused as below and set some default value

```
var focused = false;
```